# Mount UMSDOS in Windows

Tags: windows-7, drivers, filesystems

I have a directory that has `--LINUX-.---` files in it, from when it used to be mounted in a Linux system as UMSDOS.  Is there a driver that allows for mounting this directory in Windows so I can see long file names?

Alternatively, is there a Windows utility that can "extract" files from it with their long file names?

If not, I'll just fire up a VM but ideally I will be able to use this "volume" from Windows.